# Edge does not play video if server returns 304

Tags: html, video, microsoft-edge, if-modified-since

I've found that Edge doesn't work when playing videos for the 2nd time. My app is using a default `<video>` tag and Edge is sending an `If-Modified-Since` header when it loads the video for the second time. If my server returns a 304 Not-Modified it doesn't work. When I change it to return the complete video it works.

Anyone that can verify this behavior? Am I doing something wrong, should I add other things in my 304 response in order to make it work?

Btw I saw that other browsers like Chrome and Firefox never send the `If-Modified-Since` when loading the video.

Comment: At first glance this seems like a caching bug in Edge. With most servers it should be pretty easy to modify them to ignore the header on certain resources - so that can serve as a workaround if the video is not cacheable (i.e. too large).

Comment: Is the video streamed over https? Can you try over http as well if so to see if there is any difference?

Comment: @nneonneo that is what I eventually did - disable caching for edge

Comment: @AlexKeySmith it is over http have not been using https (yet)

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look on [this stackexchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25342/headers-to-prevent-304-if-modified-since-head-requests), where you can read:

> According to [this article](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/caching/), these are the situations browsers will
>   request using If-Modified-Since:
>
> - The cached entry has no expiration date and the content is being accessed for the first time in a browser session
> - The cached entry has an expiration date but it has expired
> - The user has requested a page update by clicking the Refresh button or pressing F5
>
> [...]
>
> One thing that may help is **adding "public" to the cache control**
>   header, i.e. `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000`.

You may also add `immutable`, so could you try with:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
```

Comment: thanks stefani I will try and check if this is making a difference